# How to control the space between flex items

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm just doing some learning material on Codeacademy and I'm wanting to know how to control the space between the "locations" text and the three divs below. The assignment is asking me to create a 15px space between them but I don't know how to do that. Currently, there is just a default space that I don't know how is calculated.

```css
html {
  text-align: center;
}

.location-container {
  background-image: url(https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-locations-background.jpg);
  height: 700px;
  width: 1200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#local {
  background-color: blueviolet;
}

.location-columns {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  gap: 30px;
  color: white;
}

.locations {
  background-color: black;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="location-container">

  <h2 id="local">Locations</h2>

  <div class="location-columns">
    <div class="locations">
      <h3>Downtown</h3>
      <h5>384 West 4th St</h5>
      <h5> Suite 108</h5>
      <h5>Portland, Maine</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="locations">
      <h3>East Baysuide</h3>
      <h5>3433 Phisermans Avenue</h5>
      <h5>(Northwest Corner)</h5>
      <h5>Portland, Maine</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="locations">
      <h3>Oakdale</h3>
      <h5>515 Crescent Avenue</h5>
      <h5> Second Floor</h5>
      <h5>Portland, Maine</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Thanks for any insights.

Answer (score 1):

Heading elements come with large upper and lower margins right from the default browser styles.

You can remove those for elements inside `.locations`, make it a flex container and use `row-gap` to control vertical spacing:

```css
html {
  text-align: center;
}

.location-container {
  background-image: url(https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-locations-background.jpg);
  height: 700px;
  width: 1200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#local {
  background-color: blueviolet;
}

.location-columns {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  gap: 30px;
  color: white;
}

.locations {
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  row-gap: 30px;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 300px;
}

.locations>* { margin: 0; }
```

```html
<div class="location-container">

  <h2 id="local">Locations</h2>

  <div class="location-columns">
    <div class="locations">
      <h3>Downtown</h3>
      <h5>384 West 4th St</h5>
      <h5> Suite 108</h5>
      <h5>Portland, Maine</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="locations">
      <h3>East Baysuide</h3>
      <h5>3433 Phisermans Avenue</h5>
      <h5>(Northwest Corner)</h5>
      <h5>Portland, Maine</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="locations">
      <h3>Oakdale</h3>
      <h5>515 Crescent Avenue</h5>
      <h5> Second Floor</h5>
      <h5>Portland, Maine</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I may have worded my question poorly, although it was useful info you gave I am wanting to find the reason for the gap between the h2 "Locations"(highlighted in purple) and the three divs below. How do I control that space?

Comment: The exact same way, because that gap is there for the exact same reason.